# How to set paper size in mm and draw image in the paper size I have set?

Tags: c#

I have a pre-printed "registration form" scanned on which I have to print on, I want to set my paper size to the size of my "registration form"

then I want to draw image of my "registration form" on that paper size, when I will draw it should draw within the size of paper size I have set.

**How to set the paper size to the form size?**

```
PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("Form1", 70, 170);
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
                printDocument1.Print();
```

**How to fit the image to the paper size I have set?** or draw the image within the paper size

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
Image image = Image.FromFile("form1.jpg");
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

if the question sounds confusing, please ask.

Comment: That code makes no sense; `Graphics.DrawString` takes a `string`, not an `Image`. Try `DrawImage`.

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry mistake in writing, but i am using draw image not draw string.